# node.js:134 throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I have a meteor app, when I try to start it I get the error below:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'fs'
error: no such package: 'assert'
error: no such package: 'blocking'
error: no such package: 'spin'
error: no such package: 'page-js-ie-support'
error: no such package: 'HTML5-History-API'
error: no such package: 'connect'
error: no such package: 'accounts-linkedin'
error: no such package: 'linkedin'
error: no such package: 'cfs-gridfs'
error: no such package: 'cfs-graphicsmagick'
error: no such package: 'cfs-filesystem'
error: no such package: 'power-queue'
error: no such package: 'collectionFS'
error: no such package: 'observatory'
error: no such package: 'observatory-apollo'
error: no such package: 'observatory-galileo'
error: no such package: 'http-methods'
error: no such package: 'collection-hooks'
error: no such package: 'join'
error: no such package: 'reactive-property'
error: no such package: 'micro-queue'
error: no such package: 'reactive-list'
error: no such package: 'cfs-public-folder'
error: no such package: 'cron-tick'
error: no such package: 'handlebars-server'
error: no such package: 'moment'
error: no such package: 'cfs-base-package'
error: no such package: 'collection-api'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I tried running :

```
sudo mrt update
```

to update the meteorite but I get the error below:

```
    $ sudo mrt update

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot set property inflect of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/utile/lib/index.js:41:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/utile/lib/index.js:281:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:302:12)
    at require (module.js:355:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:10:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
```

How do I fix this error for the meteor app to start?